# Moving apps to SD card

Tags: applications

My phone can't move applications to my SD card storage it keeps displaying root can't be found and that I need to change my setting to grant or allow

Answer (score 2):

You can move apps through the system's Settings: Settings → Application Management → [Target App] → move to SD card